# How to run a bash function() in a remote host? in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I am running a `bash` script, but when I try to run functions on a remote machine, it says

```
bash: keyConfig: command not found
```

Here is my script:

```
keyConfig() {
    sed -i.bak -r "/^$1/s/([^']+')([^']+)('.*)/\1$2\3/" $3
}

remoteExecution() {
    ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 " keyConfig $1 $2 $4 "
}

remoteExecution
```

Comment: +1 for well formed question. You can send a function definition "over-the-wire" thru ssh, and then execute it, but it's not really for the faint-of-heart. You'll quickly run into issues with quoting. And your sed function, filled every shell meta-char and quoting char is a perfect example of a quoting nightmare. Its possible, but fragile, and time consuming to debug and get right. You could use `scp myFunc user@remotehost:/tmp/myFunc` (as a file), and execute from /tmp. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resone for the error:

When you do

```
ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 " keyConfig $1 $2 $4 "
```

You are actually trying to execute a command `keyConfig` on remote machine `10.101.5.91`
Which is certainly not there:

2 Solution for the problem

1) Make a script on remotehost which contains `keyConfig` code with same name

OR

2) Execute following instead of function

```
ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "sed -i.bak -r "/^$1/s/([^']+')([^']+)('.*)/\1$2\3/" $3"
```

**Please note you may have to add few escape depending on the sed syntax you are using**

Comment: Thank You for your help... it worked, but in your 2nd solution this part ("sed -i.bak -r "/^$1/s/([^']+')([^']+)('.*)/\1$2\3/" $3") was not worked then I made some changes because of the double quotes @middle, so I added some aditional back slashes(\) to that. Here is this :[ "sed -i.bak -r \"/^$1/s/([^']+')([^']+)('.*)/\1$2\3/\" $3" ] then it worked. Thank You... :)

Comment: just tried with the escape near to the double quoates, but it did not work. Any idea where to put the escape you have told on the answer latter part?

Comment: give me $1 $2 $3 and exact ssh line with sed to work with, please try and conclude in your next comment as SO doesn't allow long conversations in comment

Comment: That's way I said to add some back slashes to the sed command. I said like that because I tested with that. Then no need to worry about $1, $2, $3, those are commandline arguments. check my 1st comment. Thank You...

Answer (score 6):

Simple work-around:

```
remoteExecution() {
    ssh ppuser@10.101.5.91 "`declare -f keyConfig`; keyConfig $1 $2 $4"
}
```

Here, `keyConfig` only calls `sed` command, which is available on remote system. If `keyConfig` had been calling any local function, then add that function also in `declare -f`'s command line.

This way, the function `keyConfig` in the local shell gets defined in the remote shell spawned via ssh & then it gets called.

Comment: Hello @anishsane, Thank You for your help... I tried with this but my problem is after declaring this function as u told, how to get the command line arguments from my local file?

Comment: Declare keyConfig function as you are declaring now. modify remoteExecution function as mentioned in my answer. After this do you see any error, when you run `remoteExecution` function as you desire?

Answer (score 1):

`keyConfig` is not define as a command in the host "10.101.5.91"

You could try to define a bash script which is called `keyConfig` in the host "10.101.5.91" and add that script in the `ppuser` PATH.