# On Linux, how can I share scripts across an SSH connection for the session only?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

For work, I have to connect to dozens of Linux machines via SSH (to perform maintenance, monitor the system, install software, etc).

I have a small arsenal of scripts that help me do some of these tasks, and these are located in a folder on my Mac in /Users/me/bin. I want to be able to run these scripts on the remote Linux machine, but for several reasons I do not want these scripts permanently located on these machines (e.g., other people also connect to these remote machines, and it would be unwise to let them execute these files).

**So, is possible to share scripts across an SSH connection for the lifetime of the session only?**

I have a couple of ideas on how to do this, but I don't know if any of them will work. Firstly, if SSH allows file mounting, I could automatically mount me@mymac:/Users/me/bin to me@linux:/remote_bin when I connect to the remote Linux box, and set my PATH variable to "$PATH:/remote_bin". Secondly, I could set up port forwarding in the connection string (e.g., `ssh me@linux -R 9999:127.0.0.1:<SMBPORT|ETC>` and every time I connect mount the share and set the $PATH variable.

**EDIT**: I've come up with a semi-solution. On the linux machine, edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to add the following subsystem: `Subsystem shareduserbinary sudo su -l -c "/bin/mount -t cifs -o port=9999,username=me,nounix,sec=ntlmssp //127.0.0.1/exported_bin /mnt/remote_bin" && bash -l -i -s`. When connecting to the remote machine, set up a reverse port forward and invoke the subsystem. E.g.: `ssh -R 9999:127.0.0.1:445 -s shareduserbinary me@linux`.

**EDIT 2**: You can make the solution above cleaner, by removing the `-l` from the `sudo` command and changing the path from `/mnt/remote_bin` to `$HOME/rbin`.

Comment: If other people have enough _permissions_ to execute the contents of these files, you are not protecting anything by not leaving them around.

Comment: Regardless of permissions, there are still reasons to not share these scripts with them.

Comment: lots of interesting stuff if you search here for `[ssh] function`. I partiuclarly liked a recent take on this under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23264657/how-to-run-a-bash-function-in-a-remote-host-in-ubuntu/23266213#23266213 . Look for anishsane's answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.  Perhaps you can add a command to ~/.bash_login (assuming you are using bash) to copy the scripts from a remote host (such as your mac) when you login, then add a command to ~/.bash_logout to delete the scripts when you logout.  But, as bmargulies points out, it would be a good idea to go a step further and make sure that nobody else has permissions to read or execute the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OpenSSH`'s `LocalCommand` to upload the files (using e.g. `scp` or `rsync`) when initiating an SSH session (see `man ssh_config` and [this](http://antenore.altervista.org/how-to-synch-your-bashrc-between-servers/)):

```
Host server1 server2 [...]
PermitLocalCommand yes
LocalCommand scp -q /Users/bin/me/* %h:temp_bin/
```

and use `.bash_logout` or an `EXIT`-`trap` that you specify in your `.bashrc` to delete the contents of the directory on logout.